# Using intltool with cmake

Tags: cmake, gnu, gnome, intl

I'm writing a GNOME application and use CMake. Now I'm considering making the app translatable, for which GNU provides `intltool`, `gettext`, `msgfmt`, etc.. *autotools* supports these tools and the entire i18n process out of the box.

How do I get this to work with CMake? Are there any modules or snippets of code around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowadays, the best way to use `intltool` and `gettext` together with CMake is to, first, detect if the modules are present in the system and set a few variables like this:

```
# Setting up Intl
find_package (Intl REQUIRED)
find_package(Gettext REQUIRED)
include_directories(${INTL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${INTL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
```

Then, you can build the `po` files like this::

```
FIND_PROGRAM(GETTEXT_MSGFMT_EXECUTABLE msgfmt)

IF(NOT GETTEXT_MSGFMT_EXECUTABLE)
    MESSAGE("------
    NOTE: msgfmt not found. Translations will *not* be installed
------")
ELSE(NOT GETTEXT_MSGFMT_EXECUTABLE)

  SET(catalogname rkward)

  FILE(GLOB PO_FILES *.po)
  SET(GMO_FILES)

  FOREACH(_poFile ${PO_FILES})
    GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(_poFileName ${_poFile} NAME)
    STRING(REGEX REPLACE "^${catalogname}_?" "" _langCode ${_poFileName} )
    STRING(REGEX REPLACE "\\.po$" "" _langCode ${_langCode} )

    IF( _langCode )
      GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(_lang ${_poFile} NAME_WE)
      SET(_gmoFile ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${_lang}.gmo)

      ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(OUTPUT ${_gmoFile}
        COMMAND ${GETTEXT_MSGFMT_EXECUTABLE} --check -o ${_gmoFile} ${_poFile}
        DEPENDS ${_poFile})
      INSTALL(FILES ${_gmoFile} DESTINATION ${LOCALE_INSTALL_DIR}/${_langCode}/LC_MESSAGES/ RENAME ${catalogname}.mo)
      LIST(APPEND GMO_FILES ${_gmoFile})
    ENDIF( _langCode )

  ENDFOREACH(_poFile ${PO_FILES})

  ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(translations ALL DEPENDS ${GMO_FILES})

ENDIF(NOT GETTEXT_MSGFMT_EXECUTABLE)
```